# MySQL server version syntax issue when update

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

While updating my data I am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Source Sans Pro'- sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">Concept<' at line 35

Comment: can you drop the text which you planning to update
and the query ?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` for insert larger about of text data.

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_real_escape_string.asp